# For what values of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ is the matrix $A$ invertible?

Tags: matrices, determinant

> For what values of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ is the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &x_4 \\  x_1^2& x_2^2 & x_3^2 & x_4^2\\  x_1^3& x_2^3 & x_3^3 &x_4^3 \end{pmatrix}$  invertible?

Okay, I know what those are Vandermonde matrix, but how do I find for what values is matrix invertible?

Do I need to find $\det A^{-1}$ and than definition area or what?
Help!

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: If the $x_i$ are pairwise different the matrix can be used to find the polynomial $f(x)$ with maximum degree $n-1$ and $f(x_i)=y_i$ , $i=1,...,n$. This polynomial always exists and is unique because the matrix is regular in this case.

Comment: If you have only elementary linear algebra avaiable, (I think) the only way is to compute the determinante via row-transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is invertible if and only if the $x_i$ are pairwise different. This is a well-known property of matrices of this kind.

One direction is trivial : If we have $x_i=x_j$ for some $i,j$ with $i\ne j$, we have two identical columns, so the determinant must be $0$, and the matrix singular.

The determinant of the Vandermone-matrix is equal to the product over the terms $x_i-x_j$ with all pairs $i,j$, for which we have $i< j$.

Comment: In my case $x_1≠x_2≠x_3≠_4$?

Comment: Yes, but note that what you wrote down does not imply that the $x_i$ are pairwise different. But you mean the correct thing.

Comment: Necessary and sufficient for $det\ne 0$ is $x_1\ne x_2$ , $x_1\ne x_3$ , $x_1\ne x_4$ , $x_2\ne x_3$ , $x_2\ne x_4$ and $x_3\ne x_4$.